# How to get URL last part with php

Tags: php, url

I was searching for solutions to display the current URL of the page, and I found a few ones but I don't know how to implement them and call them, so this was the best solution I've found for me because it already has the echo thingy.

```
function curPageURL() {
     $pageURL = 'http';
     if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
     $pageURL .= "://";
     if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     } else {
      $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
     }
     return $pageURL;
    }
```

And to call it, I'm calling it like this

```
echo curPageURL();
```

But I want to get only the last part of the URL, for exemple:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29237151/thequestion
```

I want to get `thequestion` part of the URL. how can I do this?

Comment: And what exactly is the last part of an URL? .com, everything after .com, the last `$_GET` value?

Comment: What do you mean by last part?

Comment: Maybe look into **htaccess**

Comment: Sorry I updated my question, I want to get for example only the part that says **thequestion**. but I don't know and don't wanna do it via htaccess, because I want to display this for only one single page

Comment: Why don't you `explode('/')` your URL then `array_pop()` the array to get last part of the URL?

Comment: Hi @D4V1D I don't know how to do this, I've found this bit of code googling it

Comment: Do you want to include get parameters and also anchors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the best way is to `explode()` then `array_pop()` your URL.

Like so:

```
function curPageURL() {

    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $url = explode('/', $url);
    $lastPart = array_pop($url);

    return $lastPart;
}
```

@Vineet answer is suitable too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @D4V1D , just one more thing, If I wanted to create an if statement like: if the last part is `thequestion` or `theotherquestion` do this, else do something else. how would I do that?

Comment: Well, just do `if(curPageUrl() == 'thequestion' || curlPageUrl() == 'theotherquestion') { /* do this */ } else { /* do something else */ }`

Comment: It's working. it was breaking the site with the second part `|| curlPageUrl() == 'theotherquestion'` but then I realized it was a misspell in `curPageUrl()` . thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'm sorry for all these questions @D4V1D , but can I also ignore if the URL has uppercase or not?

Comment: Use `strtolower()` on both `curPage()`.

Comment: Or better: just `return strtolower($lastPart);` in your function.

Answer (score 0):

In your case. Please change like

```
$url = curPageURL();
```

It will give you complete URL and then write lines as below

```
$new = explode("/", $url);
$last_part = end($new);
```

It will give your desired output.

Comment: where to I put this? I tried to remove all the code in my answer and replace it with this, but can't make it work

Comment: Are you calling your function first ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this as well

```
echo substr(strrchr(curPageURL(), "/"), 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

PHP has a function called `parse_url()` that will ... parse an URL. 
What you are looking for is the `path` part of the result.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29237151/thequestion?arg=value#anchor';
$pathParts = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$lastPart = array_pop(explode('/',  $pathParts));
echo $lastPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way I think is:

```
end(explode('/',  $url));
```